# stm32 board strange behaviour

Tags: stm32, led

could you help me?

This utility function I use to set kth bit of x zero or one.

```
#define zer(x, k) ((x) &= (~(1u << k)))
#define one(x, k) ((x) |= (1u << k))
```

I have stm32f407vet6 board. Something strange happens when I do

```
one(GPIOA->MODER, 12u);
```

led on pin PA6 turns on, like I use ODR register.

Furthemore, in my code

```
one(GPIOA->ODR, 6u);
```

turn off LED, but

```
zer(GPIOA->ODR, 6u);
```

turn it on.

Why is that so?

Why MODER register behave like ODR, and why I have ODR turn on and off inversed?

Thanks in advance.

I guess, if I out zero in port ODR, led tuns off. If I put one in port ODR, led turns on. But it behaves inversed. And setting one to moder turns on led. Why is that so?

Comment: Check your schematic, if your board is [this one](https://stm32-base.org/assets/pdf/boards/original-schematic-STM32F407VET6-STM32_F4VE_V2.0.pdf), the LED is connected between 3v3 and the GPIO pin, so setting the pin to HIGH is indeed turn the LED off.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But what about MODER? When I set register MODER to output pin, it lights my led, but it should be done by ODR register?

Comment: Hints: Read the datasheet to see what is the default value of ODR? and  what will happen when you set the MODER to output?

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is very simple.

It is better to sink than source the current through GPIO pin. So board developers connect LEDs the way they will be light when pin becomes a logical zero. Like in below schematics:

[image]

```
one(GPIOA->MODER, 12u);
```

Sets pin 6 as ***output***. As ODR by default is zero, pin is OV - the LED is ON.

Same explanation for the ODR behaviour.